# Residue at infinity of $zp'(z)/p(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Suppose a polynomial $p\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ of degree $m$ with complex roots $b_1,\ldots,b_m$. Then $$ f(z):=z\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}=\frac{z}{z-b_1}+\ldots+\frac{z}{z-b_m}.$$ I want to compute $$\text{Res}(f,\infty)=-\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^2}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right),0\right)=-\lim_{z\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{z}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=-\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}zf(z).$$ But this last limit is $\infty$. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is here $$-\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^2}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right),0\right)=-\lim_{z\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{z}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right).$$ You did the computation as if $0$ was is a simple pole but it is a double pole of $\frac{1}{z^2}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right).$ Hence you want to compute $$-\lim_{z\to 0}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)'=-\lim_{z\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{1-zb_1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{1-zb_m}\right)'=-(b_1+...+b_m).$$